# Casting and Performance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, casting

I'm writing a code that selects data from a database, store it in a DataTable, do some hard math, and updates the database back.

The main issue is that it requires a lot of casting due to DataRow collections returns columns as the object type, forcing me to do float.parse() every single row and making it time-consuming.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how I can avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not casting what you mention. It's parsing/conversion of a string to a numeric data type.

Comment: Are they coming back from the database as floats?  Could you just do (float)row["column"] instead of float.parse(row["column"])?  Not sure what the difference will turn out to be but might be worth a quick shot.

Comment: `float.parse` is *not* casting: [casting is quite fast](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpcasts.aspx)

Comment: What library are you using for data access? Can't you do something like `reader.GetFloat()`?

Comment: sorry for the lack of information, doing  (float)object does not work, I have to parser it.

Comment: +1 I would like to know that as well. For ASP.Net it is easy as I use the custom DataSet which will be strongly typed so I won't have to parse everything. In just C#.Net I don't know what is equivalent of DataSet but I assume there is going to be something.

Comment: Just use a typed DataSet instead of a stock DataSet

Comment: Also, does casting work if you go say `(float)(If(row["foo"], row["foo"].ToString().Trim(), "0"))`, you should look at why casting doesn't work rather than just accepting you have to use .Parse

Answer (score 7):

`float.Parse` is *not* the same as casting. You should be able to actually cast the value, e.g. one of

```
(float) row["Foo"]
(double) row["Foo"]
(decimal) row["Foo"]
```

depending on the type. That will avoid doing any reparsing - you're just unboxing. You may need to unbox *and* cast if the value isn't in the type you want, e.g.

```
(float) (double) row["Foo"]
```

It's unclear exactly how you're using the `DataTable`, but I would suggest creating your own model class which represents a row of a table in a strongly-typed way, with conversions to and from `DataRow` - or use a strongly-typed `DataSet` to start with. That way your code will be a *lot* clearer, and you'll only need to perform conversions for a small part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

> forcing me to do float.parse() every single row

If you need *float.parse()*, you're doing something wrong somewhere.  You should be storing the column in numeric type (float, numeric, decimal, money, etc) rather than a string type (char, varchar, nvarchar, etc), and if you're doing that the value in the datarow column *already is* a type such that you can use a simple `(float)` cast (and maybe a check for DBNull).

float.parse() is *doubly* bad, because not only do you have to parse the value from a string, but you have to first create the string to parse... you're paying for this *twice.*

Answer (score 2):

If your database returns floats, you don't have to use float.parse. Assuming you have a `DataRow row`, you can just use something like this:

```
float val = (float)row["column"];
```